# Capturing Xtrabackup metrics through MySQL DB

Tags: percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

Have anyone worked on gathering insights related to Xtrabackup process? 
I would like to analyse the various Xtrabackup performance metrics. I know that for monitoring MySQL services itself, we use the information available in tables across 'performance_schema' & 'sys' databases. Also we can make use of 'show status' MySQL command.

Is there any way to gather the Xtrabackup insights in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. `xtrabackup` is an external process to MySQL and thus there is no way for xtrabackup to report stats to MySQL for population inside PS/IS/sys. Your only option here is to tail the logfile of `xtrabackup` while it is running (or redirect to syslog and use journalctl) and utilize the log output in some way for your metrics.